# Error Importing SQL To MySQL Cluster. Missing Primary Key

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, replication, group

I hope someone can help me with this. I'm moving a MySQL database (WordPress) to a MySQL Cluster running Master-Master replication. When I'm trying to import the SQL to the database I get the following error message;

```
Plugin group_replication reported: 'Table wpmk_actionscheduler_actions does not have any PRIMARY KEY. This is not compatible with Group Replication.'
```

Ok, so I know what this means or I thought I did. When I inspect this table in PHPmyAdmin, I can see this table does have a primary key. I ran the following command to find the tables without a primary key;

```
SELECT
    tab.table_schema AS database_name,
    tab.table_name AS table_name,
    tab.table_rows AS table_rows
FROM information_schema.tables tab
LEFT JOIN information_schema.table_constraints tco
    ON (tab.table_schema = tco.table_schema
        AND tab.table_name = tco.table_name
        AND tco.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY')
WHERE
    tab.table_schema NOT IN ('mysql', 'information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'sys')
    AND tco.constraint_type IS NULL
    AND tab.table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
```

But this doesn't return any tables (because they all have keys). And yet, my damn cluster is saying a key is missing when importing the SQL. I'm totally stuck.

I attached a screenshot of the table before I exported it. What am I missing here?

[image: Table Primary key]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this myself by downloading MySQL Workbench, opening the .SQL and editing the create statements to include an ID column and set it as the primary key. Then I removed the alter statements which were supposed to add primary keys. I guess these are updates from developers.